# Can 2 elements be combined into a new release without a "clan based Kekkai Genkai"?

Tags: naruto, boruto

The Anime has stated quite a lot of times that Kekkai Genkai is a genetic leverage that some clans have, which allow them to combine 2 elements into a new style.
(Like for example, wind + water makes the ice release and Earth + lightning makes the explosion release).

What I'm more interested in thou, is if its possible for a prodigy who can use 2 elements, to combine them. To be more specific I'm asking if its possible for Boruto to create a new release by combining lightning and wind style. (I don't even know what the combination of wind and lightning creates).

I'm really interested in this because there has been some individuals who have used releases from combinations of 2 elements without being from a notable "Kekkai genkai known clan". An example is deidra, who could use the explosion style and also darui, the wiki even states that: "By combining his water and lightning-natures, he can utilise Storm Release".

So could Boruto possibly create a new release of his own by incorporating lightning style and combining it with wind nature.

Comment: No captain Yamato & kakashi made it clear while during Naruto's training for rasen shuriken, that only people having kekkai genkai blood can combine two chakra forms to form a new one , but even if you combine two different jutsu you will call it either collaboration or combination of jutsu ex: Sasuke, Naruto's combined scorch realese nibus tempest (combination of wind style rasen shuriken & infrno style susano flame control arrow)ps: I don't know the spellings.

Comment: i don't mean a collaboration technique. I mean simultaneously using the 2 elements to create a new style.  Also, Darui's ability to use storm release was only attributed  to him combining 2 elements. The anime never spoke about him being from a storm release renowned clan

Answer (score 2):

### Indeed, two or more elements can be mixed and utilized without it being clan based.

According to the *Naruto* wiki:

> Wood Release (木遁, Mokuton, Viz: Wood Style) is a nature transformation kekkei genkai, a combination of Earth and Water Release. It was famously used by Hashirama Senju, and in fact is not known to have naturally occurred in anyone else, leading to it being regarded as impossible to use without having his cells.

Wood Release is a Kekkei Genkai only **naturally** used by Asura Otsutsuki and Hashirama Senju. Asura received Wood Release after Hagoromo Otsutsuki, the Sage of Six Paths, passed his power onto him. Wood Release is also of Otsutsuki lineage, another possibility as to why Asura has it. Hashirama most likely has it being his former reincarnate. This power is a mixture of two elements not used by any Senju except Hashirama.

The wiki also states:

> A kekkei genkai (血継限界, literally meaning: Bloodline Limit) is an anomaly of the DNA that allows the wielder to use unique techniques. A kekkei genkai's name describes both the anomaly and the resulting technique.

You are not wrong on this part. But Kekkei Genkai are shown to not only be bloodline abilities. They are also known to be the mixture of two elements, not needing to be passed down. Examples of this are Hashirama, and Haku. Boruto may be able to make a new Kekkei Genkai, but as of now, it has not been shown.

### Final Answer

Yes, it is true that Kekkei Genkai are typically known to be abilities passed down by family, examples being the Hyuuga's Byakugan, The Uchiha's Sharingan, and the Chinoike Clan's Ketsuryugan. But Kekkei Genkai are also known as the mixture of two elements.