# How did Moegi acquire the Wood release

Tags: naruto, boruto

[image]

Wood release is the kekkai genkai of the Senju clan (originally the God trees sacred ability and also the Otsutsuki clans Kekkai Genkai), however, [Moegi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Moegi_Kazamatsuri) is able to do it by combining Water and earth style. [Does this mean being able to combine 2 elements can allow anyone to use an advanced element?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49153/can-2-elements-be-combined-into-a-new-release-without-a-clan-based-kekkai-genka)  We know Orochimaru used to perform experiments on merging [Hashirama](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Hashirama_Senju)'s cells with small children but Sarutobi Hiruzren (the Third Hokage) put an end to it.

Moegi did not have the wood style ability while she was younger plus the experiments that Orochimaru did with Hashirama's DNA were destroyed earlier in the series. So how did Moegi suddenly become able to use it at adulthood?

Comment: I always thought that Boruto world can't be held true to the Naruto world's rules. That is why I never started watching it.

Comment: Nah its the other way round actually @Bej . Boruto is a continuation of Naruto, the exact same logic and universe. Just with a new Generation and some technology.

Comment: I started watching at first but it felt like they did a permutation combination and combined multiple abilities into a single character. I just made peace with the fact that I will not be able to watch Boruto without comparing it to Naruto and so I stopped watching.

Comment: If they followed naruto logic, then how did this moegi guy question come to be?

Comment: lol thats what i'm trying to find out @Bej . Think about it this way tho, the newer generations are usually "stronger" than the previous ones. Plus like most of the kids inherited abilities from both parents so it kinda makes sense why most of the newer characters have multiple abilities.

Answer (score 1):

One thing before I answer the question: wood style is not the Senju clan's bloodline. In order for it to be a clan's bloodline, multiple people in the said clan would have to be able to use it. I believe that Hashirama was able to use wood style due to being the reincarnation of Asura. Asura is an Otsutsuki and as we found out, the Otsutsuki clan can use Wood style.

As for how Moegi can use it, I believe that she is capable of using the yin-yang release and combining it together with her water style and earth style, thus creating wood style. Think about it: Hagoromo was able to *create* life by utilizing the yin-yang release. Also, yin release creates form from nothing while yang release creates life, combine those two and you have a living lifeform.

Genjutsu uses yin release, Outer Path's ability uses yang release, Creation of All Things utilizes yin-yang release, using both imaginations to make the Tailed-Beasts bodies while at the same time giving life to forms without any. 670 page 17, 449 page 1-3.

This is just my theory.

Comment: It's not true that kekkei genkai will be available to all the clan members. It's kekkei thota that can be taught. An example of a character who is the only member of his clan use their kekkei genkai is kimimaro of the kaguya clan.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know who said this, but she figured it out by using Yin–Yang Release, but that's not just some common style of jutsu that anyone can learn out of the blue. Not to mention if it were that so simple, the 3rd Hokage or even Orochimaru would have perfected and recreated the jutsu easily.

The 3rd ―during a time that probably took place after The Second Great Ninja War and allowed experiments before canceling out of fear― wouldn't have needed to use such risky experiments hoping the 1st cells would bond with host in order to use it. He was known as the professor and knew every jutsu within the Hidden Leaf, and that includes secret hidden jutsu passed down in clans like the Shadow Possession jutsu, the Human Expansion jutsu, and even the Mind transfer jutsu.

So, Yin–Yang Release wouldn't have been a problem for him to use and combine those two elemental changes in chakra with Yin–Yang Release to make the wood style, except that's not what created the wood style, and so many wouldn't have died to experiments trying to get it. Orochimaru continued the experiments with Danzo and thought he failed, but Yamato became the only other one.

Now I am aware Moegi can use it to and I wish we could see it, but it's not Yin–Yang Release. It just doesn't make sense and Kishimoto would have made clear it's needed in order to use it.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. I've tried to improve the readability, but if I accidentally changed the meaning, feel free to [edit] and fix and/or add more details. Thanks.