# Is the databook consistent with the series about Sasuke and Kakashi being faster than Naruto?

Tags: naruto, boruto

According to the official databook 1,2,3, Sasuke and Kakashi are faster than Naruto. According to the last one, Naruto speed is a 3,5 out of 5, (like a 7 out of 10) and Sasuke and Kakashi are a 4,5 out of 5 (like a 9 out of 10) . But in internet, I see a lot of discussions stating Naruto is faster than Sasuke, and putting as example that once or twice Naruto dodged a light speed attack. I wonder if there is an explanation for this? Perhaps the last databook doesnt cover those events? Perhaps it is inconsistent with the series? Perhaps it's indeed true that Sasuke is faster than Naruto?

Is the databook consistent with the series about Sasuke and Kakashi being faster than Naruto?

Comment: Not an answer, but the data books seem to contain a few things that lack quality explanations (as also seen with [Moegi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/49165/20275)  supposedly being able to use Wood Style)